# Adjective/adverb for "taboo"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase that means something along the lines of "the exhilaration of taboo".

Here's the context for what I'm looking for: "It was strange and *[blank]* to walk around and see everyone's age so blatantly public."

Comment: Do you mean that their ages were _displayed_ in a blatantly public manner? What is taboo about that? At first glance, _thrilling_ might be a fit.

Comment: I agree with @coleopterist ~ can you provide another example?  Or at least explain how people see "everyone's age," and what's so taboo about it?

Comment: Erm... **taboo/tabu** *is* an adjective (as well as a noun). I'm having trouble thinking of how the concept could be used *adverbially*. By and large, an action is either taboo or it's not - I don't really see how you can do something "in a taboo manner".

Comment: @coleopterist Yes their ages were evidently displayed in a blatantly public manner. See what is apparently the OP's blog post in which this context appears: http://kennysong.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/triathlon/

Comment: @ΜετάEd: Great detective work there! I do wish posters would stop extracting sentences and pasting them on EL&U without their surrounding content; so often, the preceding sentences are absolutely vital in correctly interpreting a word or phrase.  In this case, I think "titillating" and "guilty pleasure" both fit the title of this question just fine, but, unless I had some strange age fetish, I'd hardly use those words to describe the feelings I'd have at a triathlon starting line, seeing the ages of my fellow racers.

Comment: @MετάEd Cheers :) I would probably just say "It was _strangely thrilling_ to ..."; there's nothing really taboo here even if you consider an eastern cultural influence. If anything, it's simply something of an open breach of etiquette.

Comment: I think all the answers so far have been off the mark because 'taboo' is really too strong a term for what has been breached here. 'Taboo', even outside its original anthropological context, denotes something strenuously forbidden.

Answer (score 3):

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/titillating) defines *titillating* as

> of or relating to something that arouses, teases, interests, or excites someone pleasurably and often superficially  *He writes deliberately titillating lyrics.*

[Merriam-Websters](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/titillating) offers

> pleasantly stimulating or exciting , such as *titillating reading*; also: erotic

Comment: This word flashed right into my gutter-ridden mind.

Answer (score 2):

"Guilty pleasure" is a common phrase.   Also consider *[hedonic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hedonic)*, which while it denotes no more than pleasure or pursuit thereof, often connotes breaking taboos. (In noun form, *[hedonism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hedonism)*.)

*Edit:* In the example sentence, one might replace *[blank]* with "gave us a *[frisson](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frisson)* of *[Schadenfreude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schadenfreude)*" or "... of *[superiority](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superiority)*".  Knowing others' ages is not taboo, I think, and no age is to be looked down upon, but one imagines some do.

Comment: Hm, it's not exactly what I'm looking for -- I added some context for the question if you want to take a look.

Comment: Is Mercozy a variant of *[Merkozy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Merkozy)* ("(slang, politics) ... unified position of France and Germany ... Blend of Merkel ... and Sarkozy")?  Anyway, I agree the phrase is a mix, I should have written "a peccant piquancy" instead.

Comment: I don't think *hedonistic* has any real connection with *taboo*.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if our BE phrase  ***felt a bit naughty***  would fill the bill in the context you give.

Answer (score 1):

How about: "it was strange and [transgressive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transgressive)"?

Answer (score 1):

Since what is breached here appears to be a norm or convention rather than a taboo, how about 'provocative', which is often used in a positive sense: it is not only base or improper sentiments which may be provoked but also serious matters like political opinions or aesthetic judgments. At the very least using 'provocative' leaves room for some ambiguity which is itself, well, provocative.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Julia Kristeva's theory on abjection and the abject. I would use abject in this sentence.

The abject is a disturbance in identity and order that threatens the collapse of meaning, causing abjection, in which the viewer is rapidly and cyclically compelled and repelled. The abject blurs the distinction between "other" and "I." Kristeva identifies the corpse as the ultimate abject.

In your context, the blatant display of age evokes impending mortality, one that transcends the "other" elderly lives into the life of "I," a reminder that all bodies are biologically destined for failure. This evokes an existential breakdown in meaning, but as you described, there's a sense of exhilaration. That's the boomerang effect of the abject, it attracts (the exhilaration) and repulses (the taboo).